# How to remove specified characters in a label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change texts every time that user click on a button. So, if the user clicked on specified button the "✓ " characters will be added to that button's text. Also, if the user clicked on another button, That characters will be removed from the previously clicked button's text.

I tried the first code below to add the "✓ " characters and it worked well without problems. Then I tried to remove the checkmark by replacing + into -
and I got some issues running it.

```
English_Language.Text = "✓ " + English_Language.Text;

//-----------

English_Language.Text = English_Language.Text - "✓ ";
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove a character from a string you cannot just subtract. That is undefined, if there is more than one, what will happen? So you must use one of the methods on the string class in to get the result you want. If you only have one of those characters, or you want them all gone then you can use `Replace`, otherwise, you can use `SubString` as follows.

```
English_Language.Text = English_Language.Text.SubString(1);
```

Using `SubString` in this way will skip the first character seeing as that's where you are placing the character.